# Material change detection in dynamic, Angular reactive forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, material-design

I am building a complex form application running Angular 6. This application builds  the questions within the form itself (`form-component`) with an `*ngFor` loop on a separate `question-component` selector. The `question-component` lists out the HTML for each type of form input (text, datepicker, radio, checkbox, etc), and depending on the question type being passed in from the `form-component`, it will build the necessary HTML element for that instance of the question component. I'm handling some important logic as a `(change)` event on the `question-component`'s selector tag within my `form-component`.

```
   <section
      *ngFor="let section of formData"
      class="form-section"
      [hidden]="section.hidden"
      [id]="section.programmaticName">
      <h1 id="{{section.programmaticName}}">{{section.displayName}}</h1>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>

      <!-- Questions -->
      <div class="question-container" *ngFor="let question of getSectionQuestions(section.programmaticName)">
        <app-question
          [question]="question"
          [hidden]="question.hidden"
          [form]="formData"
          [id]="question.programmaticName"
          (change)="dataChange($event)">
        </app-question>
      </div>
    </section>
```

This was all working fine until I tried to add Material as my UI. Some of Material's form elements do not support `(change)`, and instead require their own specific methods (i.e. `(selectionChange)` for selects, or `(dateChange)` for the datepicker). And unfortunately, those elements which are incompatible with `(change)` obviously cannot detect those changes anymore.

Without handling the change method at the question level (where each question type could have its own change detection method), how would I go about resolving this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!